# Configure w3m with Emacs Error

Tags: python, emacs, w3m

I am trying to configure and use w3m with emacs 23.  I have w3m on my system and have downloaded and make/install emacs-w3m 1.4.4.  However, when I put (require 'w3m-load) into my .emacs file it throws an error on emacs startup:

```
File error: Cannot open load file, w3m-load
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I thought I had tried it all and it ends up being a pretty embarrassing fix.  I didn't have the load path added in my .emacs file so it didnt know where to find w3m-load.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "PATH TO w3m")
```

Comment: You should mark this as answered :) - You can also explicitly specify the `w3m` location.